# PHP extending mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with extending the `mysqli_result` class.

I am trying to extend the `mysqli_result` class with a custom class.
Here is my code:

```
class mysqli_result_extended extends mysqli_result {

  public function GetJSON() {
    blah blah...
    return $json;   
  }       
}

$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','*****','somedb');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM students';

$result = $db->query($sql);

$result->getJSON(); //This is causing the trouble
```

When I run the above code, it gives an error:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli_result::getJSON() in ****.php on line **
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the `$db->query($sql)` returns a variable of type `mysqli_result` and not `mysqli_result_extended`. The `mysqli_result` class doesn't have a method named `getJSON`.

So when you define a class `B` that extends class `A`, it **doesn't mean** that all instances of the base class `A` magically become class `B`.